# Icon set in Visual Studio 2015 for C# Console App ends up looking super aliased

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015, icons

I am creating a console app in c# using VS 2015(Community Edition) and I decided to add an icon to the exe today and it looks perfect in the preview [Preview in VS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQGVh.png)
But once I actually build the app it turns out looking like it was downscaled using nearest neighbor and looks [Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HINAp.png) and it gets worse the smaller the icon gets scaled.

I've tried using icons of sizes ranging from 256x256 to 16x16 but not of them turn out favorably. Is there something I'm missing? I also have all the icons in the resources list.